# Multiple file project in Gummi

Tags: gummi

Im using a LaTeX template to write my thesis, I was working with TeXMaker but I would want to use Gummi in Linux. The LaTeX template has multiple files, a main, a config, chapters, etc., and when I try to work with it in Gummi, I cant preview anything. This is the log I get. What can I do?

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/psikonetik/Desktop/TeXiS-v1.0-ManualSrcICT/Capitulos/.01Memoria.tex.swp
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
/home/psikonetik/Desktop/TeXiS-v1.0-ManualSrcICT/Capitulos/.01Memoria.tex.swp:3
6: Undefined control sequence.
l.36 \chapter
             {Memoria}
/home/psikonetik/Desktop/TeXiS-v1.0-ManualSrcICT/Capitulos/.01Memoria.tex.swp:3
6:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/.01Memoria.tex.log.
```

Comment: Without more detail we can't really help here. I do notice the `.swp` extension, which suggests files from Scientific Word. We really need a full MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Your log says that the `\chapter` command is not defined. This has some possible explanations:

- You have a project **split into multiple files** and gummi is trying to compile one of the part files, not the main file. If you open the main file in gummi, it should compile everything, including the part you are currently editing.
- Or you're using a `documentclass` that does not define chapters, such as `article`. Try using `\documentclass{book}` or `\documentclass{report}` instead.

Comment: But it works in Texmaker for example...Anyway, the document class is defined in de main.tex, and this is the output log of the Memoria.tex, wich is a chapter of the project.

Also, I've checked the documentclass in the main.tex and it's this one [11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

And if I try to compile the main.tex this is what I get in the log

Comment: mm the website doesnt allow me to put so many characters...

Comment: If you like, you can [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/113225/edit) your original question to include the compilation log from `main.tex`.